# Problem with accents in portuguese on varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

I have a table with 2 varchar columns. One of this columns has to store the name of an item in portuguese. The problem is when i make an insert, appears some strange letters. Even if i make an update, they still appear.

This is my table definition:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items](
    [idItem] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name_es] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [name_pt] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [Items] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [idItem] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

And this is what happens

[image: Table with strange letters]

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You’re using VARCHAR which doesn’t like non-English characters so try and use the data type NVARCHAR instead